# Why would a regression model predict super huge numbers?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I have a set of 55 items.  Each item is defined by 6 values.  I am doing 55-fold cross validation: training a model on 54 items, predicting on the 55th.  The 6 values of the 54 items are used in some feature engineering to produce feature sets (we have a couple we are testing).

I then predict 1 value at a time, so I have 6 54-length "ground truth" vectors for each fold.  Thus, it's 6 models for each fold.  4 of the 6 parameters do not make sense as being negative (they are parameters of a gamma distribution).  So, to account for this, I have taken the natural log of the ground truth in the training set, then exponentiate the predicted value by base $e$.

I have tried a variety of regression algorithms with a grid search over parameters: SVR, Ridge, and Random Forest Regressors are the current top contenders.

However, in all of the models, there is usually a couple parameters that get predicted way off base. As in orders of magnitude off base. I think it's because of the log space but I don't think I can not use log space because of the negative numbers.

I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this problem correctly, or if there is something trivial I am not seeing.

Comment: You didn't get the answer yest probably because it is not really clear what is your data and what kind of problems do you get. Could you provide a boarder description and a an example of your data and results you get? This problem *is* manageable but the answer is dependent on your data so there is no immediate answer.

Comment: Sure and thanks for the response Tim.  It's hard for me to describe because it's kind of a complicated problem.  I am in the middle of deadlines right now, but I'll post back soon =).